# Como concatenar una varibale int y str en un trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy haciendo un trigger en sql el cual me concatena una palabra con un numero, asi esta:

```
create or replace trigger TG_curso_Auto
before insert on cursos
for each row
declare  var int;
begin
    select count(*)+1  into var from cursos;
    :new.siglas := concat(:new.siglas,'-',var);
end;
/
```

Aqui var es una variable tipo entero que nesesito concatenar con un string, pero no se como pasarlo a string, la tabla cursos simplemente tiene una id y una sigla

```
create table cursos
     id number(7) not null,
     siglas varchar(4) not null);
```

Para explicar mejor el ***var*** empieza desde 1 y a medida que se le agrega algo va sumando de 1 en 1... al intentar insertar en la tabla cursos por ejemplo (`insert into cursos values (12345,'Bases')`) deberia poner en la columna ***siglas*** *Bases-1* luego algo como *siglas-2*, *siglas-3*...

Alguna idea de como resolver este problema o no es posible hacer esto?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utiliza la función [`to_char`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm), por ejemplo de la siguiente manera:

```
:new.siglas := :new.siglas || '-' || to_char(var);
```

En este caso, el campo quedará en `null` si ya traía un valor null. Si no es el comportamiento deseado, también puedes utilizar `coalesce`, por ejemplo

```
:new.siglas := coalesce(:new.siglas, '') || '-' || to_char(var);
```

Answer (score 1):

para concatenar puedes usar las dobles barras: `campo1 || '-' || campo2`